# How to set sequelize.sync option force to false?

Tags: mysql, node.js, heroku, sequelize.js

I am deploying a node.js app using a mysql database and using sequelize ORM on heroku. When I deploy, sequelize re-creates the database. The application does not work because it expects data in the database.

I believe sequelize.sync option is the culprit. On my local development env, I have set force: false by hand. But on heroku, sequelize is being reinstalled (package.json) and I am guessing sync is defaulting to force:true.

How do I set an option to stop this behavior? I went through the doc and tried this:

```
var sequelizeOptions = {
    host: "blah.blah.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com",
    dialect: 'mysql',
    port: 3306,
    sync: {force:false}
};
```

This is being passed to the sequelizeManager that in turn is handling the creation of DB. This approach is is not working. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sequelize.sync` is an options object, that simply dictates how the sync should be performed when it is called, and FYI, `force` is `false` by default. The issue is that you are calling `sequelize.sync()` somewhere in your code, likely in the same place where you are registering your models. You need to prevent your code from executing `sync()`.

Comment: Thanks. Spot on. I tracked down where sync() was being invoked. No more sync and no more re-creation issue.

Comment: I call sequelize.sync({force: false}), but still the tables are re-created. Why is this?